# How can I accelerate iron corrosion in a way that simulates natural processes?

Tags: electrochemistry, corrosion

I am attempting to conduct a research project comparing the effect of various current levels on electrolytic rust removal. Somewhat ironically however, I need a way to induce corrosion in a predictable and fast manner so as to have a standard baseline from which to conduct my experiment. Ideally it would somewhat resemble natural corrosion so that the data is applicable outside of a laboratory setting. Thank you in advance to anyone who answers.

Comment: Not my area, but have you checked any of the corrosion-relevant ASTM (American Society for Testing and Materials) publications? Corrosion of steels is a big topic, so there may well be standard protocols for preparing test specimens, testing corrosion inhibitors, etc. Best of success!

Comment: A general way to speed corrosion is to use a mix of salt, hydrogen peroxide and vinegar (5% acetic acid), https://ctsciencecenter.org/blog/science-at-play-instant-rust/ As @EdV states, this might be used in some ASTM corrosion resistance tests.